# Complicated non-linear relationship

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, gradient-flows

I came from an engineering background, so please excuse my ignorance in math.

Am looking for a mathematical interpretation for the following figure, here it is obvious that Z follows a non-linear behavior with x,y. 
if it is a one variable function we normally take its derivative and equate it to zero to find the maxims.

However, in this figure am dealing with a PDE and am clueless.

Please think of it as you are looking into mathematical problem and direct me where to look or what you think the pattern means, to be more exact, what does the marked points mean?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: If it were a topographic graph the marked points would be the easiest climb to the top. Not the path of steepest ascent, but the "most gentle" path of ascent. Not my field, perhaps there is a technical name for it.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, thanks John, it is not a topographic graph, however your hint is something that might have a physical meaning in the system.

Comment: @Mark_XI : It looks like the maximum $z$ is in the top left of the graph. The marked points are at the maximum distance for that contour from the max $z$.
Do you know what the physical process is and what x,y,z are physically?

Comment: Actually, now that I am awake I see that it is actually the "line of steepest ascent" from the leftmost marked point, the path taken by following the gradient. The numbered lines are the level curves of $f(x,y)$ and the marked points are following one of the gradient lines which are orthogonal to the level curves. They indicate an attempt to find either a local minimum or local maximum point on the surface (depending upon whether one starts with the leftmost or rightmost point.) One computes the gradient $\nabla f\left(x_0,y_0\right)$ at current position, moves a bit in that direction, repeat.

Comment: The marked points could be points of maximum curvature of the contours. I don't know of a name for this. Also, you could look up "flow lines" which are perpendicular to the contours (following the gradient).

Comment: @arthur: you are correct, the top left is the maximum and the min contour is the bottom left. Physically, the contours (z) represents the difference between two friction models, at different operating points (x,y). I hope this helps

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, great observation John, I was thinking this way and I have another figure to show the gradients at each point, and yes the marks are looking for local max and min( with each one has a specific physical meaning).

Comment: @KeithMcClary, this is the mathematical terminology looking for, that describes the maximum curvature of the contours.